# How to decode a .csv .gzip file containing tweets?

Tags: pandas, csv, utf-8, gzip, decode

I'm trying to do a twitter sentiment analysis and my dataset is a couple of .csv.gzip files.
This is what I did to convert them to all to one dataframe.

(I'm using google colab, if that has anything to do with the error, filename or something)

```
apr_files = [file[9:] for file in csv_collection if re.search(r"04+", file)]
apr_files
```

Output:

```
    ['0428_UkraineCombinedTweetsDeduped.csv.gzip',
     '0430_UkraineCombinedTweetsDeduped.csv.gzip',
     '0401_UkraineCombinedTweetsDeduped.csv.gzip']
```

```
temp_list = []

for file in apr_files:
    print(f"Reading in {file}")

    # unzip and read in the csv file as a dataframe
    temp = pd.read_csv(file, compression="gzip", header=0, index_col=0)
    
    # append dataframe to temp list
    temp_list.append(temp)
```

**Error:**

```
Reading in 0428_UkraineCombinedTweetsDeduped.csv.gzip
Reading in 0430_UkraineCombinedTweetsDeduped.csv.gzip
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2882: DtypeWarning: Columns (15) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
Reading in 0401_UkraineCombinedTweetsDeduped.csv.gzip
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-5cba3ca01b1e> in <module>()
      3     print(f"Reading in {file}")
      4     # unzip and read in the csv file as a dataframe
----> 5     tmp_df = pd.read_csv(file, compression="gzip", header=0, index_col=0)
      6     # append dataframe to temp list
      7     tmp_df_list.append(tmp_df)

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb8 in position 8048: invalid start byte
```

I assumed that this error might be because the tweets contain multiple characters (like emoji, non-english characters, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I just switched to Jupyter Notebook, and It worked fine there.
As of now, I don't know what was the issue with Google Colab though.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).